# SHA1 password encryption error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sha1

I'm trying to perform a login check agains the credentials stored in a database where email is a plain text and password is saved as SHA1. For now, the users have been created manually. To check the login details I decided to use stored procedure.
Here's the problem:

The following query returns password in SHA1:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'password') 
 // returns 0x5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8
```

The following query confirms user existence:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from users where email='test@gmail.com'
 and password='0x5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8' // returns 1
```

And now here comes the stored procedure (the select statement extracted from the whole procedure where 'password' is a placeholder) which does not seem to return 1 as it should:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from users where email='test@gmail.com'
 and password=(SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'password')) // returns 0
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What is the data type of `password`? Are you storing a string or varbinary? Why is your varbinary value surrounded in quotes (second query)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT HASHBYTES() returns type varbinary and your password column seems to be a varchar.

Solution as working for OP:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from users where email='test@gmail.com' and password=(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', 'password'), 1, 0))
```

Comment: Well the password column used to be NVARCHAR(100) but after I changed it to VARBINARY(100) the problem remains...I will try to play around with the conversions though

Comment: Does VARBINARY(100) truncate the entries at all?

Comment: The solution to this problem is that the password column is set to VARCHAR(40) so that it fits the value and the password coparison is done this way: SELECT COUNT(*) from users where email='jpodwysocki@gmail.com' and password=(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', 'password'), 1, 0)). Thank you!

Comment: I would think a better solution is to store a varbinary password as varbinary and not bother converting back and forth to a string. That just seems like a lot of extra work for nothing.